# ASP MVC Access View Model from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP MVC 4 and jQuery.
I want to get ViewModel properties from the javascript.
I tried some solutions from stackoverflow, but none of them was working for me.
Hope you Help me.

Thanks

Comment: You have you to have you javascript in your razor file to do this. Do you have yours in your razor file? This link should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391402/access-model-in-javascript-asp-net-mvc-razor

Comment: I am trying to access to view model from external js file.

Comment: This is not possible. The only way around this is to declare a global JavaScript variable in the razor file from the model and use that variable from you external js file.

Comment: Is your view a strongly typed?

Comment: Can you please give me exact steps or useful links? @Derek

Comment: @Alexander                     <td class="ts-table-cell">
                        @{
                            date = Model.dates[3].ToString("dddd dd MMMM");
                        }
                        <p class="">@date</p>
                    </td>

Comment: I have added the steps as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access model properties from external JavaScript files so you have two options. You can include all of your JavaScript in the razor file as seen in the link below.

[access model in javascript asp .net mvc razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391402/access-model-in-javascript-asp-net-mvc-razor)

Otherwise you can set a global JavaScript variable and use it in your external file as seen below.

razor.cshtml

```
@model Order
<script>
    var isEdit = '@Model.IsEditable'
</script>
```

externalfile.js

```
function getEdit() {
alert(isEdit);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Derek You saved me much time. Thanks again

Comment: No problem I am just glad we got you moving forward!