# Kendo UI - Pass parameter to JS function within read().data()

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, .net-core, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I need to pass various parameters back to my controller method, which I am able to do in the following ways:

Parameters From Model:

`.Read(read => read.Action("CPos_Read", "Reporting", new { LocCode = "#=LocCode#" }))`

Parameters From Javascript Method:

```
.Read(read => read.Action("CPos_Read", "Reporting").Data("GetFilters"))

function GetFilters() {

    var ParamList = [];
    var Param = ":";

    Param = "DateStart:";
    Param += $('#DateStart').val();
    ParamList.push(Param);

    Param = "DateEnd:";
    Param += $('#DateEnd').val();
    ParamList.push(Param);

    return { Params: ParamList }
}
```

I have a requirement to pass both the LocCode parameter from my kendo grid model, and the additional parameters from the Javascript function. In other words, I need to be able to combine both of these to pass back to my controller.

Ideally, I would like to be able to pass the LocCode parameter to my Javascript method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [access model in javascript asp .net mvc razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391402/access-model-in-javascript-asp-net-mvc-razor)

Comment: Please bare in mind that the model is not a view level model. It is a model that the kendo grid is assigned to. I have multiple kendo grids within my view (sub grids), each with a different model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a working syntax for passing a kendo grid's selected model value into the Javascript function:

```
.Read(read => read.Action("cPos_Read", "Reporting").Data("GetFilter(#=LocCode#)"))
```

I researched for quite a length of time before I posted here and did not find any examples of this being done, even though it appears quite simple. Hopefully the code above will help someone in the future.

Comment: Where is the Data() method defined? It doesn't seem to be available to me in Telerik UI version 2018.1.117.