# JavaScript error when using @Html helper

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I saw [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16361364/accessing-mvcs-model-property-from-javascript) but when I used it in my MVC 5 VS 2013 app it throws "Invalid Character error  The char is the @

```
$(document).on("click", "#btExtendDates", function () {
var _date =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PmntDate));
```

});

Adding quotes doesn't work either. It returns a literal string (Which I believe is correct)

```
var _date =  '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PmntDate))'
```

Comment: This code is in Javascript file or in a cshtml?

Comment: This approach would only work in the view file - cshtml that is.

Comment: The view is a partial and wont run the script section I will need to rewrite then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Html.Raw/Json.Encode` is an HTML helper which can be used only in .cshtml file.

Please move your js code that refers Html helper classes from JavaScript file to cshtml

or atleast the below part

```
<script>
 var _date = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PmntDate))
</script>
```