# Strongly Typed Model Access?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

When I have a strongly typed model like so

```
@model Person.Models.Person
```

Can I access the values in jQuery?

Furthermore, if I have an input like this, and it is edited, is the value stored in my model also changed?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="@Model.FirstName" id="FirstName" placeholder="First Name">
```

I'm new to MVC, so I don't really understand this `@model`

My sincere thanks for your answers

Comment: I strongly suggest reading some basic tutorials first, [http://www.asp.net/mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc) for example.

Comment: yes, you can access the values from jquery, this post might help you on that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16361364/accessing-mvcs-model-property-from-javascript

Comment: You can assign a model property to a javascript variable using `var firstName = '@Model.FirstName';` but its the initial value of the model. If you want to access the edited value then you need to access the value of the control - `var firstName = $('#FirstName').val();`

Answer (score 0):

yes you can access all model values in jquery.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var name=@Model.name;
    //or
    alert(@Model.msg);
});
```