# How do I change value of a model using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using **Asp.Net MVC** and I have a model where has an attribute `status` and in the`form` has 2 `input type =" submit "` to submit the `form`, they are:`save and post` and `save`. I want to when I click on button `save and post` change`status` attribute to value 1, and when user click on button `save` change`status` to value 0.

To do this I'm trying use JQuery getting the `id` of `input` and change  the `status` attribute, but still can't do it.

How could I do this ?

**html**

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save Post" id="savePost"/>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save" id="save" />
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#addPropriedade').submit(function () {        
        var dados = new FormData($('#addPropriedade').get(0));

        $('#savePost').click(function () {
            dados.status = 1;
            console.log(dados.status);
        });
        $('#save').click(function () {
            dados.status = 0;
            console.log(dados.status);
        });


        $("#errorMessage").hide();

        var loading = $("#div_loading");
        $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
            loading.show();
        });
        $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
            loading.hide();
        });

        $.ajax({
            accepts: { json: 'application/json' },
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Propriedade/addAjax",
            data: dados,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data) {
                var status = data["status"];
                var msg = data["msg"];
                if (status === "1") {
                    $('#addPropriedade').trigger("reset");
                    $("#errorMessage").html(msg);
                    $("#errorMessage").prop("class", "alert-success");
                    //window.location.replace("/Empresa/view");                    
                } else {
                    $("#errorMessage").html(msg);
                    $("#errorMessage").prop("class", "alert-danger");
                }
                $("#errorMessage").show()
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                $("#errorMessage").html("Erro tentando cadastrar");
                $("#errorMessage").prop("class", "alert-danger");
                $("#errorMessage").show()
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Is your click function getting triggered ? when you click on save and post button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
$('#addPropriedade').submit(function () {        


    $('#savePost').click(function () {
    var dados = new FormData($('#addPropriedade').get(0));
        dados.status = 1;
        console.log(dados.status);
    });
    $('#save').click(function () {
    var dados = new FormData($('#addPropriedade').get(0));
        dados.status = 0;
        console.log(dados.status);
    });


    $("#errorMessage").hide();

    var loading = $("#div_loading");
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        loading.show();
    });
    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        loading.hide();
    });

    $.ajax({
        accepts: { json: 'application/json' },
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Propriedade/addAjax",
        data: dados,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var status = data["status"];
            var msg = data["msg"];
            if (status === "1") {
                $('#addPropriedade').trigger("reset");
                $("#errorMessage").html(msg);
                $("#errorMessage").prop("class", "alert-success");
                //window.location.replace("/Empresa/view");                    
            } else {
                $("#errorMessage").html(msg);
                $("#errorMessage").prop("class", "alert-danger");
            }
            $("#errorMessage").show()
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            $("#errorMessage").html("Erro tentando cadastrar");
            $("#errorMessage").prop("class", "alert-danger");
            $("#errorMessage").show()
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

});

Comment: it doesn't change value of `FormData`, look at my JQuery script, I'm using `FormData`

Comment: What are you trying to do excatly ? When user clicks on save button you are trying to post the formdata at the same time you need to set the staus to 0 correct ?

Comment: yep, the FormData send to controller as a `Model`. The `status` is an attribute of `Model`, can you understand ?

Comment: You need to intalize the form data inside the click function. I have update my answer

Answer (score 2):

Hi The simple solution i think is , if you are using the jquery in the same cshtml file where the model is strongly typed.

Then you can directly access the model object using the @ character.

**Example:**

var status = '@model.status'

And then you can assign whatever value you want.

**Detailed example with all other types has explained very well in the below link:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41312348/3397630

Hope it was helpful, kindly let me know your thoughts or feedbacks

Thanks

Karthik