# JavaScript function changes date string parameter to a series of numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, razor

I have a JavaScript function within an MVC Razor View. The View is passed a model which contains two strings to represent UK dates, e.g., **dateFrom** 01/03/2018 and **dateTo** 31/03/2018 .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    function LoadDatatable(to, from)
    {
        alert(to);
        alert(from);
    }

    LoadDatatable(@Model.dateFrom, @Model.dateTo);

});
```

These date strings are then passed to the function `LoadDatatable`, however, the dates are completely changed when this happens. The screenshot below shows the alert prompt for the dateTo string which was passed into the function as 31/03/2018.

[image]

Can someone please help? I need the function not to change the passed date strings.

Comment: You just discovered the difference between a text literal ... and a _mathematical operation_ ...

Comment: _“I need the function not to change the passed date strings?”_ - you just need to actually pass strings, which so far you simply didn’t.

Comment: `LoadDatatable('@Model.dateFrom', '@Model.dateTo');`

Comment: Hint: take the date, e.g. `1/4/2018` and type it as-is into Windows Calculator, or into Excel with an `=` before it. Also, doing a bit of Browser > View Source would have revealed the problem rather quickly...

Comment: It's been a long day - silly mistake - thanks folks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the date like this, It should work.

```
function LoadDatatable(to, from)
{
    alert(to);
    alert(from);
}
LoadDatatable('@Model.dateFrom', '@Model.dateTo');
```

Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16361364/accessing-mvcs-model-property-from-javascript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) more on this.

Comment: No. This passes `dateto` and `datefrom` as string literals. It also doesn't show the OP how to include their razor syntax

Comment: Yes changed now, ohhh you commented the same.!