# accessing model data from javascript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, model

I want to access model data from javascript 
[Accessing MVC's model property from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16361364/accessing-mvcs-model-property-from-javascript) 
my problem is similar to this but whenever i use the solution given here

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

or

```
var floorplanSettings = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.FloorPlanSettings));
```

it returns null exception ... where as i already have data in database.
other solution such as `var Name = '@Model.Name';`show syntax error ....
what is the solution for this?? can anyone help me with this!!

Comment: If your getting a `NullReferenceException`, then the model is `null` in your view!

Answer (score 0):

Does this produce the expected result?

`var model = @(new HtmlString(Json.Encode(Model)));`