# Access model property from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an ASP.NET MVC project and I am trying to access a model property (isNew) from the view (.cshtml) and from within javascript function so I am performing below without success:

```
@model My.Common.DTOs.MyDTO

function Initizalize()
{
   if (!@Model.isNew)
   {
      DoSomeStuff(); // call another javascript function
   }   
}

function DoSomeStuff()
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by this way

```
if (!@Model.isNew)
{
  <script>
   DoSomeStuff(); // call another javascript function
  </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this at your scripts section.

```
@section scripts{
  <script>
      var isNew = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.isNew));

      function Initizalize()
      {
          if (!isNew)
          {
              DoSomeStuff();
          }   
      }

      function DoSomeStuff() {

      }

      Initizalize();

  </script>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16361364/accessing-mvcs-model-property-from-javascript/16361388) question related to your problem? There's a pretty in-depth answer on how to access model data in Javascript/Jquery code block in a .cshtml file. Best of luck.